# Is freeglut the standard OpenGL Window manager on Linux?

Tags: linux, opengl, porting

I'm going to be porting a java OpenGL game engine that I wrote in Java to C on Linux.

My main question is what is the **defacto** Window management utility to use for OpenGL applications in Linux? Is it `freeglut`?

If `freeglut` isn't what is most commonly used; then what tends to be the most used?

Comment: I don't think there's one that dominates to the extent that you could call it a de facto standard. I would, however, say that freeglut (or any glut implementation) should be close to the bottom of the list of those you'd consider (if you insist on putting it on the list at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "defacto" OpenGL window management utility on any platform. FreeGLUT is commonly used, but that doesn't mean anything. What matters is what you use it *for*.

In general, FreeGLUT is not for "serious" applications. It's for self-contained demos, tutorials, and the like. While there are APIs to give you control over the main loop, the default API (the one that 99.9% of sample code will use) has FreeGLUT manage the main loop. For most games involving time pressure or animation of some kind, this is generally unacceptable.

You may be able to get your code working under FreeGLUT (though there's no reason it can't just be Java code either), or you may not. But also be advised that FreeGLUT doesn't have very good input routines (at least, not for games), and it has zero sound capabilities.

Comment: For new visitors, GLUI has better FreeGLUT compatibility than it used to back in 2012 when this answer was written, so it might be a viable option. At least the examples work.  "GLUI is a GLUT-based C++ user interface library which provides controls such as buttons, checkboxes, radio buttons, and spinners to OpenGL applications."